# How is Cygwin tool different from linux terminal? Is there any slowness issue in Cygwin

Tags: ruby, linux, cygwin

Hi I was working on some Ruby stuffs and I need to use Linux terminal or Cygwin. Which is the best choice? Is there any slowness issue in Cygwin

Comment: Perhaps you could improve this question by giving detail of what you are trying to accomplish, answer what platform you would run Cygwin on, and why.  As to slowness, not really, it is running its own executables, rather than really being more of a virtual host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is pretty subjective to what it is you are really wanting to do.  If you need access to the Windows environment, then Cygwin is going to be your choice of the two.  mingw32 is often used rather than Cygwin.

I have used Cygwin-X and Cygwin tools for more than a decade.  But I think Linux is better if you can do so.

Answer (score 0):

I use Cygwin occasionally when I am traveling and I have not encountered any lag